# Does Google Directions API take accounts to traffic?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

i know in the google map application for android, it does. However i am not sure if it does for driving direction using https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the google directions API won't factor traffic into its calculations. As far as I know, the traffic information comes from somewhere else and the google maps application gets both direction information and traffic information and handles factoring them together.

Answer (score 0):

yea I'm trying to get this feature working, looks like gm.getdirections() takes command line kargs.  maybe with that?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure why, but it seems the directions API is always a fully 'static' reply. In other words, current conditions have no impact on the response.

I wrote this in a question to get it verified, but as far as i'm aware it's currently like this:

1. In the free API it will not look at traffic at all
2. In the paid API it will look at traffic, but not reroute, just tell you the estimated actual duration of the trip
3. In all Google end-products Maps does take into account traffic and
   will reroute accordingly.